# Gitlab created a new folder when it should have used an existing one

Tags: git, bash

I added a new file to the directory `folder` within my working directory. Everything in there had already been add to my repo, except this one file.

I ran the following commands in my Windows bash shell:

```
mrjf@mypc MINGW64 project (master)
$ git add folder/My\ File\.cs

mrjf@mypc MINGW64 project (master)
$ git commit -m "Added file"
[master 69fc746] Added file
 1 file changed, 276 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 folder/My File.cs

mrjf@mypc MINGW64 project (master)
$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 1.78 KiB | 304.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
To gitlab.mydomain.com:name/project.git
   428a719..69fc746  master -> master
```

While it has successfully committed the file to my project's repository, it has created a new folder. I now have this structure within Gitlab:

```
project\FOLDER\1.cs (initial commit)
project\FOLDER\2.cs (initial commit)
project\folder\myfile.cs (Added file)
```

I should have this:

```
project\FOLDER\1.cs (initial commit)
project\FOLDER\2.cs (initial commit)
project\FOLDER\myfile.cs (Added file)
```

On my PC, it's all correct. So, Is it case sensitive when committing files? I thought it would be intelligent enough to realise that on my local machine, the files all live in the same directory, rather than creating a new one. I even used auto complete to fill in the folder/filename.

Comment: `git` is as smart as you make it, check out the https://gitirc.eu/git-config.html manual and look for `core.ignoreCase`

Comment: Note also that this has nothing to do with GitLab; it's a Git thing.

Comment: Thanks, I'll change my settings. Chris - It's a bit like asking a SQL question and not specifying the type of database though, sometimes it is relevant to include more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(putting comments into an answer)

`git` is as smart as you make it, check out the [git-config manual](https://gitirc.eu/git-config.html) and look for `core.ignoreCase`

And as @chris said: this is not something that has to do with `GitLab` per se, but with the way you decide that your local checkout should be done.

Note also that `git` defaults to case-sensitive.